# mapbox with markers and checkboxes - disable all from showing on initial load?

Tags: mapbox, marker

I have a page I built to display wind direction/velocity in various locations along a bike trail:
  http://microflush.org/cgi-bin/pathInfo.cgi

I have several markers in a legend, with check boxes to enable/disable them from showing up on the map.

My goal is to have NONE of the checkable markers show up on the initial load.  However, when the page is loaded for the first time, ALL show up-- even though they're not checked.  If I select 1, they all go away except for the one I selected, which will then disappear if I un-check that box.

Is there a way to make them all be invisible at first, and only show up if they're selected?

(You can view the source of the link above to see the code.  I wasn't sure if I should post that all, since it's kinda long with all the points I've added.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  The 'var map' needed to be defined earlier in the code.  Working properly now.